# Создание словаря из эксель с условием

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x

Есть эксель таблица вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

необходимо создать словарь где номер столбца это ключ а номера пустых ячеек это значения
При попытке сделать это следующим способом

```
f = r'R:\TEST\TESTXLS.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(f)
for cols in df.columns:
    b.setdefault(cols,[])
    if df.loc[cols]=='nan':
        b[cols].append(df.loc[ID])

print b
```

появляется ошибка `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Как правильно написать код чтобы избавиться от этой ошибки ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть такой фрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan, 2, 3,4 , np.nan], 'b': [6, np.nan, 8, 9, np.nan], 'c':[1, 2, np.nan, 5, 34]})

>>> df

    a    b     c
0  NaN  6.0   1.0
1  2.0  NaN   2.0
2  3.0  8.0   NaN
3  4.0  9.0   5.0
4  NaN  NaN  34.0
```

В вашем случае это фрейм из эксель файла.

Тогда есть такие варианты.

***Вариант 1.***

```
dict_of = {i: df[df[i].isna()].index.to_list() for i in df.columns}

>>> dict_of
{'a': [0, 4], 'b': [1, 4], 'c': [2]}
```

***Вариант 2.***

```
dict_of = {key: [k for k, v in value.items() if np.isnan(v)] for key, value in df[df.isna().any(axis=1)].to_dict().items()})

>>> dict_of

{'a': [0, 4], 'b': [1, 4], 'c': [2]}
```

Comment: у меня ошибка появляется ``AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isna' Подскажите где может скрываться ошибка. Попробовал использовать isnull пишет AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isna'``Версия pandas 0.18.1

Comment: в каком из вариантов?

Comment: в варианте 1 эта ошибка, второй вариант не пробовал

Comment: тогда в будущем предоставляйте свои данные, чтобы на них можно было проверять, а так это выстрел в небо. на этих данных работает, причем оба варианта. так что пробуйте другой вариант или выложите данные

Comment: так на скрине как раз данные на которых я пробую. Фрейм создаю такой конструкцией ``df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(f))``

Comment: зачем вы из фрейма создаете фрейм? оставьте просто *pd.read_excel*

Comment: да спасибо поправил

Comment: при использовании варианта 2 появляется ошибка ``TypeError: Not implemented for this type``

Answer (score 0):

Заработал вот такой вариант

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
dict_of = {i: df[df[i].isnull()].index.tolist() for i in df.columns}
```

ввиду работы на старых версиях `isna` был заменён на `isnull`, `to_list` на `tolist`. Предварительно был установлено новый индекс